# bokeh widget: custom css

Tags: python, css, bokeh

Is there any way to provide a custom CSS when making widgets in bokeh? E.g.:

```
        country_picker = widgets.MultiSelect(value=[],
                              title='country',
                              options=list(self.df['country_code'].unique()) + ['All'],
                              width=180,
                              height=120,
                              css=""".bk-layout-scale_height .bk  widget-form-input {
                                      height: 180px !important;} 
                              """)
```

I have one particular multi-selector that has 60+ options, so I'd like to make it high. While I'd like to keep other multi-selectors small.

Comment: I opened feature request on it, so please vote: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5471
Conversation: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/3Kvf0N_6MrQ

Comment: Nice. I wonder how hard that would be? Seams doable.. May be even with inheritance, instead of modifying the core..

Answer (score 0):

With the related [PR5503](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5503) which has been  recently merged into 0.12.5 it looks like that:

```
    country_picker = widgets.MultiSelect(value=[],
                          title='country',
                          options=list(self.df['country_code'].unique()) + ['All'],
                          width=180,
                          height=120,
                          css_classes=['myclass'] 
                          """)
```

I'm not sure how to describe the 'myclass' rules using bokeh yet.

Comment: I've asked a separate question on how to describe this class and posted an [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48848784/237105) how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for `MultiSelect` widgets, you can set the number of visible items with [`MultiSelect.size`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.inputs.html#bokeh.models.widgets.inputs.MultiSelect.size) instead of using custom css:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import MultiSelect

multi_select = MultiSelect(title="Option:", value=["foo", "qx"],
                           options=[("foo", "Foo"), ("bar", "BAR"), ("baz", "bAz"),
                                    ("qx", "Qx"), ("hid1", "Hid1"), ("hid2", "Hid2")])
multi_select.size=6
show(widgetbox(multi_select))
```